# Problem declaring and calling internal metthods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I declare and use small helper functions inside my normal methods ?

In on of my objective-c methods I need a function to find an item within a string

```
-(void) Onlookjson:(id) sender{
    NSString * res = [[sender gstring] copy];
    persInfoBirth.text = getKeyValue(res, @"Birth");
}
```

I came up with a normal C type declaration for helper function getKeyvalue like this

```
NSString * getKeyvalue(NSString * s, NSString * key){
   NSString *trm = [[s substringFromIndex:2] substringToIndex:[s length]-3];
   NSArray *list = [trm componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
   //....
   NSString res;
      res = [list objectAtIndex:1];
   //...    
   return res;
}
```

Example input string in s:

s=@"{ Birth = "1910"; Death = "1936"; }";

Anyway I get an exception "unrecognized selector sent to instance" for any of the two first lines in the helper function

How do I declare helper functions that are just to be used internally and how to call them safely ?

regards

Martin

Comment: Please read your question after saving and see if it is understandable - this one was not as the code needed to be formatted

Comment: Where are Input, Birth and Death defined?

Comment: `NSString * res = getKeyValue(res, @"Birth");` - Where is `res` declared that is part of the first argument ? If it is declared somewhere else, where are you differentiating between the current scope `res` and the other `res` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the real code? Do you get zero errors and warnings from the compiler? You must not ignore compiler warnings and you should turn on the Static Analyser in addition to the standard warnings.

There are many things wrong with the above code, most of which are nothing todo with declaring and calling methods. There is no way the above code could compile so maybe it pasted incorrectly or something..

Anyway.. declaring and using methods. Why are using a c function? Unless you have a good reason why not use Objective-c ? If you do have a good reason to use a C function the your definition should be:-

```
NSString *getKeyvalue( NSString *s, NSString *key ){
  ...
}
```

note the arguments. As NSString instances reside in the heap (not on the stack) you always want to pass pointers to them.

You then need to put the declaration in the header file:-

```
NSString *getKeyvalue( NSString *s, NSString *key )
```

**EDIT**:

In Objective-c there is no distinction between *normal methods* and *helper methods*, there is only one kind, and you have aleray written one

```
- (void)onLookJson:(id)sender { .. }
```

Taking it apart..

1. All methods begin with + or –, indicating **Class method** or **Instance method**. As you are familiar with C++ i guess you know what this means.
2. (void) is the return type. ie this method doesn't return a value. If it did it might look like (float) or (NSString *) or (id).
3. *onLookJson:* is the method name and the method takes 1 argument. Notice that the '**:**' is actually part of the name. This method is never is any circumstance just 'onLookJson'. An argument must always follow the :, so a method that doesn't take any arguments must not have one.

Ex

```
- (NSString *)fullName { .. }
```

This is an instance method, for example of a Person Class, you would call it like:-

```
NSString *theName = [aPerson fullName];
```

So

- a method name that takes no
  arguments is like 'speak'
- a method
  name that takes 1 argument is like
  'speakTo:'
- a method name that takes 2
  arguments is like 'speakTo: language:'
- a method name that takes 3
  arguments is like 'speakTo: language: volume:'

etc.

All that is left is to put in the argument types and names.
Your function definition:

```
NSString *getKeyvalue( NSString *s, NSString *key ){
```

would become..

```
- (NSString *)getValue:(NSString *)s key:(NSString *)key { .. }
```

again, you need to declare it in the header or you will get a compiler warning.

```
- (NSString *)getValue:(NSString *)s key:(NSString *)key;
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my bad typed question ! The code was not real as it was typed and not copied.
As it stands now it compiles with no warnings .
Coming from the C# world I have not read all I should on Cocoa (yet) and struggle with a lot.

Why is it a C function ? well for starters I don't know how to declare the object version ? please advice

The the trm string is just a way to try to cut off the leading and trailing {} from the input string. There must be better ways to do that than my substring attempts 

How do I declare an call a function like getKeyvalue i Cocoa ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually came up with something similar myself, but was confused that there were no function name like I was used to. Still I don't know how to call this function ?

Comment: Now I tried with a call like: persInfoBirth.text = [self getValue:res key:@"Birth"]; which actually does make the call, and hits a breakpoint inside the func. inspecting the two parameters holds correct value, but removing all other code and just returning the parameter s stil gives an exception,why ?

Comment: I see now that the problem lies with the string I pass in which look like a normal string in the debugger console but is actually from a dictionary of type __NSCFDictionary and has a count of 9 CFBasicHash type=immutable dict, count = 9

If I pass a literal NSString to the function called as [self getValue:res key:@"Birth"]; all goes well.

I guess I need to figure out how to extract the string I really want from the JSON dictionary before I can process it with getValue function.

What I've learned so far is an NSString * may not be exagtly that although i print ok in the console.

Comment: You should have a compiler warning if you assign a dictionary to an NSString *

Comment: There were no warnings from this assignment ?
The good thing was that, being a dictionary, I could just use [res objectForKey:@"Birth"] and get exagtly what I wanted without any helper function :), however now I know how to make one.
Thanks for helping me!